# JQuery Mobile - Dynamic Count Bubbles

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am creating a JQuery Mobile application that has a listview. I am populating that listview with the results of a web service. Because of this, the items in the list view are being populated as shown here:

```
$.each(results, function (i, result) {
  var s = "<li><h2 style='padding-left:40px;'>" + result.title + "</h2><p style='padding-left:40px;'>";
  s += result.subTitle;
  s += "</p><span class='ul-li-count'>" + result.count + "</span></li>";

  $("#resultListView").append(s);
});
$("#resultListView").listview("refresh");
```

My listview is being populated correctly. The value for the count bubble is showing. However, the UI does not render the bubble. Is there a way to dynamically build a result set with count bubbles in a list view? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way should work. The only thing I can think of is that the HTML is not valid.

Anyway, I created a simple version to show that it's possible. http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/HDUqp/

Basically, just build up the HTML for `<li/>` and append to the list, then call `.listview('refresh')`

```
$('#page1').bind('pageinit', function(e, data) {
    var n = 0;
    $('#addResult').click(function(e) {
        var $list = $('#resultListView');

        n++;
        $('<li/>')
            .append($('<h2>', { text: 'Title ' + n }))
            .append($('<p>', { text: 'SubTitle ' + n }))
            .append($('<span />', { text: n, class: 'ui-li-count'}))
            .appendTo($list);
        $list.listview('refresh');
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 by me cause your example works, but I seriously suggest not chaining the `append()` method with new jquery objects per your example.  Its more efficient to build a string of the HTML then call `append` once.

Comment: I normally use templates for generating HTML. For the sample I just wanted to make sure the proper HTML was created.

Comment: @shanabus I think that it is perfectly reasonable to use the append in this manner. In all but the most popular sites this little bit of javascript is not going to impact the performance as perceived by the user nor by the operations staff taking care of the servers. The readability is better in this case than the alternative string concatenation.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyKing - you are probably right, it may not matter much. It sort of depends on how much data is being loaded.  Observe the results of these guys' tests - http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly. I like the verbosity, but does that trump usability?  Guess it all depends on your target audience, but on my phone I'll take all the performance I can get.